# How can I install the node.js modules for a single user on Linux (without root permisions)?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js and npm. Many tutorials recommend to install the packages globally (i.e. with the -g switch). For instance, the [official react native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) uses

npm install -g expo-cli

However, on my Debian GNU/Linux system, this requires root permissions (which you may not have and that in any case, it is always a bad idea for security reasons)  and
mixes things with the packages from the distribution (that install at /usr/lib/node_modules/).

On the other hand, if I install them without the -g switch, the modules are installed from each project and downloaded again every time.

I would like to have a package repository on my /home directory but that all my projects can find it. Is there some way to do it? Something like an npm search path?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `prefix` option that allows you to do just that. See the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) for it. There are also a few other options you may want to consider, like `npx` or using a node version manager.